# XPages: Notes-Object of type org.openntf.domino.impl.Document is used across threads

Tags: browser, xpages, lotus-notes

Can someone explain what this means? I don't have a clue... not even when it's happening. I'd be happy to supply code, but I wouldn't even know where to start.

Thanks.

More on the message:

```
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Erreur d'interpréteur de script, ligne=1, colonne=17 : [TypeError]     
Exception lors de l'appel de la méthode NotesXspDocument.getItemValueString(string)
Notes-Object of type org.openntf.domino.impl.Document is used across threads! 
This Thread: Thread[Thread-8,5,main] correct Thread: Thread[Thread-11,5,main]
Notes-Object of type org.openntf.domino.impl.Document is used across threads! 
This Thread: Thread[Thread-8,5,main] correct Thread: Thread[Thread-11,5,main]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Notes-Object of type org.openntf.domino.impl.Document is used across threads! 
This Thread: Thread[Thread-8,5,main] correct Thread: Thread[Thread-11,5,main]
```

The document itself opens normally. The error occurs when I open a home-made value picker, that uses a jsonRpcService control.

And more:

I found the place where the NotesXspDocument.getItemValueString(string) was executed. It turned out to be in a DataContext variable that I could do without easily. The DataContext couldn't reload its value from the dominoDocument1 object (beats me why). Result: the Error 500 regarding the Thread stuff is no longer there, but I got a different one in exchange.

It only occurs when I use a Dojo dialog box, and an RPC control.

The new error: Error 400 Bad request.

Caused by: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonException: Chaîne littérale de classe com.ibm.jscript.types
.FBSUndefined inconnue
    at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator$Generator.outLiteral(JsonGenerator.java:169)
    at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator$Generator.outObject(JsonGenerator.java:214)

### Update (June 16th)

Even more info, now somewhere else in our code:

```
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:dominoDocument1.getItemValueString("Form")=="MProcessus"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

As far as I can see, the same error occurs when saving dominoDocument1 and one value was changed.

### Update (June 26th)

A virtually identical message is produced when using the code below (sporadically). It happens on the line that computes isCurrentVersion, see the arrow.

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" dojoParseOnLoad="true"
    dojoTheme="true" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="dominoDocument1" formName="MProcessus">
            <xp:this.postOpenDocument>...</xp:this.postOpenDocument>
            <xp:this.querySaveDocument>...</xp:this.querySaveDocument>
            <xp:this.postSaveDocument>...</xp:this.postSaveDocument>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
        ...
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad>...</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:this.afterPageLoad>...</xp:this.afterPageLoad>
    <xp:this.afterRestoreView>...</xp:this.afterRestoreView>
    <xp:panel style="margin: 0 auto;position:relative" styleClass="fixedWidth" id="Document">
        <xp:table style="width: 100%" id="DocumentTable">
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td style="width:#{javascript:return UserData.getScreenWidth();}px" align="left">
                    <xe:switchFacet id="switchFacet2">
                        <xe:this.selectedFacet><![CDATA[#{viewScope.buttonsFacet}]]></xe:this.selectedFacet>
                        <xe:this.facets>
                            <xc:ccDocButtons xp:key="Doc" dialogAction="dbAction" dialogMail="dbMail"
                                isModel="#{javascript:viewScope.isModel}" isEditable="#{javascript:dominoDocument1.isEditable()}"
                                isEditor="#{javascript:viewScope.isEditor}">
-->                             <xc:this.isCurrentVersion><![CDATA[#{javascript:dominoDocument1.getItemValueString("VersionCourante")=="TRUE"}]]></xc:this.isCurrentVersion>
                                <xc:this.isOriginalVersion><![CDATA[#{javascript:!dominoDocument1.getItemValueInteger("aAIndice")}]]></xc:this.isOriginalVersion>
                            </xc:ccDocButtons>
                            <xc:ccActionButtons xp:key="Action" dialogAction="dbAction" dialogMail="dbMail"></xc:ccActionButtons>
                        </xe:this.facets>
                    </xe:switchFacet>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
```

Inside ccDocButtons, isCurrentVersion is used like this:

```
    <xp:image url="/actEnregPlus.jpg" id="image15" alt="Enregistrer comme nouvelle version"
        title="Enregistrer comme nouvelle version" styleClass="clickable">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.isEditable && !UserData.isReadOnly() && compositeData.isCurrentVersion  && !compositeData.isOriginalVersion && !compositeData.isModel}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

Comment: Can you say whether you are using openNTF java api?  What projects from openNTF are you using in your app?

Comment: I try to use only the openntf class replacements from the Extension library, i.e. Session, Database, Document, the lot. You're right, I should have mentioned that I started using the API only recently. I was hoping it would help me to avoid the recycle() nightmare.

Comment: some background code or concepts would be helpful.  If I ever saw that message it's been a long time.  OpenNTF API does help avoid the recycle() issue.  I use it every day with no recycle problems.

Comment: Thanks all. More info above.

Comment: Simple comment: DO NOT STORE DOMINO OBJECTS in scopes, beans or anywhere ;-)

Comment: I know... And afaik I didn't... But I'll check again tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in scopes or beans whatsoever. More in the question above, maybe I should ask a new one...

Answer (score 3):

This can occur when you try and put a document in to one of the scopes ( application, session, view or request ). Domino objects cannot be stored in a scope because they are recycled once the page is loaded and then your attempt to access the object again results in an error.

With the OpenNTF Domino API the same things happens but the error is different because it tries to recreate the handle to the original object but it then detects that it is a different thread making the request so it throws up the error.

I think the first thing to do is check to see if you are trying to store a document in the scope and if you are recode the application to just store the unid to the document and then use that to get the document again in your value picker.

Answer (score 0):

OpenNTF Domino API errors should get logged to a file in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT called org.openntf.0.0.log. That may help track down the location of what's triggering it, if the stack trace points back to a particular Java method you're using. The most recent version of XPages Log Reader picks up the OpenNTF Domino API logs as well as the normal server files from IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT.